# Include file in php showing error

Tags: php

i have a include file with my connection details. I am trying to connect to a database but i am getting this error :

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: servername in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aditya\register.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: database in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aditya\register.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: username in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aditya\register.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: password in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aditya\register.php</b> on line <b>
```

db_info.php

```
 <?
    global $servername = "localhost";
    global $username="root";
    global $password="******";
    global $database="test";
    ?>
```

register.php

```
 <?php
require ('db_info.php');

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Get rid of the `global` declarations.

Comment: @jeroen still has the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the global declarations.  You dont need global declarations for database connection parameters.
2. Put all your database connection code in one file.  move the connection string from register.php into db_info.php.

so your db_info.php should be like:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="******";
$database="test";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    }catch(PDOException $pe){
//handle exception
}
```

Include the db_info.php file in other files where you need db connection.

Comment: now the error is `undefined variable conn`. I tried ` global conn` but its stil throwing the same error. Both the files are in the same folder.

Comment: Put the following lines on top of your file where you are including db_info.php. error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors","on");  You should now see the exact problem causing this issue